# How can I convert .epub files to plain text?

Tags: format-conversion, epub

I'm able to view an epub file in, say, okular, select all the text and copy-paste into a text editor. I'd like a command line method - anyone know of such a thing?

Comment: I'd recommend You to use some firefox epub-reading extension instead of an okular.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I don't know if Calibre is worth installing for your job, but if you have it you could use the powerful ebook converter:

`ebook-convert input.epub output.txt`

Output format is deducted from output file extension

I imagine there could be some XML tools/scripts (XSLT) that can transform epub in text as epub is basically XHTML in ZIP archive

Comment: Calibre (and it's "ebook-convert") is very powerful tool indeed! Thanks!

Comment: If you've installed calibre on OS X, the command line tool can be found here: `/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-convert`.

Comment: If you use the command line tool, you might have to configure or set options to get proper output or you could end up with the wrong encoding when converting from epub to plain text for example. Using the app interface, default settings seems to work fine.

Comment: from the documentation, "The options & defaults change, depending on both the input & output formats, so you should always check with: `ebook-convert input.format output.format -h`" (see: https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/ebook-convert.html )

Answer (score 10):

An alternative is [**epub2txt** by Kevin Boone](http://web.archive.org/web/20190119083640/http://kevinboone.net/README_epub2txt.html), available on [Github](https://github.com/kevinboone/epub2txt).

> epub2html is a simple command-line utility for extracting text from EPUB documents and, optionally, re-flowing it to fit a text display of a particular number of columns. It is written entirely in ANSI-standard C.

Usage example:

```
epub2txt input.epub > output.txt
```

Comment: from the linked github page (as of 2020): _"Please note that this version of epub2txt is obsolete. It has been completely re-implemented as a new project, epub2txt2"_ https://github.com/kevinboone/epub2txt2

Answer (score 9):

[MuPDF](https://mupdf.com/) can convert from `epub` to `html` and `txt`. To install it:

```
sudo apt install mupdf mupdf-tools
```

To use it:

```
mutool convert -o somefilename.txt somefilename.epub
```

It assumes `txt` output from the `-o` option.

See `mutool convert` [documentation](https://mupdf.com/docs/manual-mutool-convert.html) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) can suit your needs.

See [What formats does calibre support conversion to/from?](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#what-formats-does-calibre-support-conversion-to-from) for information on supported formats.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

To convert an epub document to plain text from terminal:

```
pandoc input.epub | lynx --stdin --dump > output.txt
```

It is assumed that `pandoc` and `lynx` are already installed.